# How to fix ButtonGroup bleeding out of Grid container Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Here is the code and the output it's pretty self-explanatory: I am trying to build a responsive layout and for some reason the button group will bleed out of the container and even get bigger when the screen size decreases.

```
<Container className="container">
            <Grid container>
                <Grid item xs={12} md={12} lg={6}>
                    <Chessboard
                        position={tour.fen}
                        isDraggablePiece={isDraggable}
                        onPieceDrop={onDrop}
                        customArrows={arrows}
                        onSquareClick={dropPiece}
                        onMouseOverSquare={mouseOver}
                        onMouseOutSquare={mouseOut}
                        customSquareStyles={{ ...options }}
                        customBoardStyle={{
                            borderRadius: "4px",
                            boxShadow: "0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)",
                        }}
                        customDarkSquareStyle={{ background: "#90a2ad" }}
                        customLightSquareStyle={{ background: "#dfe3e6" }}
                    />
                    <ButtonGroup variant="contained" className="controls">
                        {isFirst ? (
                            <Button onClick={randomStart}>Random Start</Button>
                        ) : null}

                        {tour.visited.length !== 0 ? (
                            <Button
                                disabled={tour.completed !== null}
                                onClick={finishTour}
                            >
                                Complete Tour
                            </Button>
                        ) : null}

                        {tour.completed !== null ? (
                            <Button onClick={visualiseComplete}>
                                Visualise
                            </Button>
                        ) : null}

                        {tour.visited.length !== 0 ? (
                            <Button
                                onClick={() =>
                                    setArrows(genArrows(tour.visitedStr))
                                }
                            >
                                Show path
                            </Button>
                        ) : null}

                        {tour.visited.length !== 0 ? (
                            <Button onClick={undo}>Undo</Button>
                        ) : null}

                        {tour.visited.length !== 0 ? (
                            <Button onClick={reset}>Reset</Button>
                        ) : null}
                    </ButtonGroup>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={12} md={12} lg={6}>
                    <Moves tour={tour} />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            {/* <CompletedPanel tour={tour} impossible={impossible} /> */}
        </Container>
```

[Desktop version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pd3Sl.png)
[Mobile version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bx75D.png)

I expect the the button group to fit inside the container and become stacked vertically

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps make a responsive size value with `useTheme` and [`useMediaQuery`](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-use-media-query/) from Material UI, and try with one or more of the following approaches.

Simplified live demo: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2jourh?file=src/App.js)

Import the helper hooks:

```
import { useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import useMediaQuery from '@mui/material/useMediaQuery';
```

In the component, create responsive condition:

```
const theme = useTheme();
//  Customize this with preferred breakpoints
const matches = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up('sm'));
```

In the output, try one or more of these approaches for responsive values:

```
<ButtonGroup
  //  Make size based on responsive value
  size={matches ? "medium" : "small"}
  variant="contained"
  aria-label="outlined primary button group"
  //  Define maxWidth for the group
  sx={{ maxWidth: "100%" }}
  //  Conditional shorter text
>
  <Button>{`${matches ? "complete " : ""}tour`}</Button>
  <Button>{`${matches ? "show " : ""}path`}</Button>
  <Button>undo</Button>
  <Button>reset</Button>
</ButtonGroup>
```

As an alternative option, perhaps also consider to make the `ButtonGroup` layout horizontal when in smaller screen size:

```
<ButtonGroup
  size={matches ? "medium" : "small"}
  //  Conditional orientation
  orientation={matches ? "horizontal" : "vertical"}
  variant="contained"
  aria-label="outlined primary button group"
  sx={{ maxWidth: "100%" }}
>
  <Button>complete tour</Button>
  <Button>show path</Button>
  <Button>undo</Button>
  <Button>reset</Button>
</ButtonGroup>
```